# Extracting same lines from two files while disregarding lower/uppercase

Tags: python, bash, perl, unix, awk

The aim is to extrac the same lines from two files while disregarding lower/uppercase and also disregarding punctuations

I have two files

`source.txt`

```
Foo bar
blah blah black sheep
Hello World
Kick the, bucket
```

`processed.txt`

```
foo bar
blah sheep black
Hello world
kick the bucket ,
```

Desired output (from `source.txt`):

```
Foo bar

Hello World
Kick the, bucket
```

I have been doing it as such:

```
from string import punctuation
with open('source.txt', 'r') as f1, open('processed.txt', 'r') as f2:
  for i,j in zip(f1, f2):
    lower_depunct_f1 = " ".join("".join([ch.lower() for ch in f1 if f1 not in punctuation]).split())
    lower_depunct_f2 = " ".join("".join([ch.lower() for ch in f2 if f2 not in punctuation]).split())
    if lower_depunct_f1 == lower_depunct_f2:
      print f1
    else:
      print
```

Is there a way to do this with `bash` tools? perl, shell, awk, sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to do this using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {s=toupper($0); gsub(/[[:blank:][:punct:]]+/, "", s); a[s]++;next}
   {s=toupper($0); gsub(/[[:blank:][:punct:]]+/, "", s); print (s in a)?$0:""}' file2 file1
Foo bar

Hello World
Kick the, bucket
```

Comment: does it load the whole file into the memory? nothing is printing when testing on 1.5 mil lines =(

Comment: It loads lines from only 1st file into memory and then it compares that with second file. Also you didn't mention in your question about the big volume of the data.

Comment: oh it worked after a couple of seconds, no worries, as long as it works reasonably fast, it's okay

Comment: yes it did work but i'm not getting good internet connections for the past few days, i'll relook into the problem soon...

Answer (score 2):

The Perl solution is quite similar to the Python one:

```
open my $S1, '<', 'source.txt'    or die $!;
open my $S2, '<', 'processed.txt' or die $!;
while (defined(my $s1 = <$S1>) and defined (my $s2 = <$S2>)) {
    s/[[:punct:]]//g for $s1, $s2;
    $_ = lc for $s1, $s2;
    print $s1 eq $s2 ? $s1 : "\n";
}
```

Note that the result is different from yours, as the space after `kick the bucket` was not removed.

Answer (score 1):

Bash solution, quite sinmilar the Perl one, with the same different result (as the space after `kick the bucket` was not removed):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch

exec 3<> source.txt              # Open source.txt and assign fd 3 to it.
exec 4<> processed.txt
while read <&3 varline && read <&4 varpro
do
    varline_noPunct=`echo $varline | tr -d '[:punct:]'`
    varpro_noPunct=`echo $varpro | tr -d '[:punct:]'`
    [[ $varline_noPunct == $varpro_noPunct ]] && echo "$varline" || echo 
done
exec 3>&-       # Close fd 3.
exec 4>&-
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this solution helps you :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $f1 = $ARGV[0];
open FILE1, "<", $f1 or die $!;
my $f2 = $ARGV[1];
open FILE2, "<", $f2 or die $!;


open OUTFILE, ">", "cmp.txt" or die $!;

my %seen;
while (<FILE1>) {
      $_ =~ s/[[:punct:]]//isg;     
    $seen{lc($_)} = 1;
}

while (<FILE2>) {
    my $next_line = <FILE2>;
    $_ =~ s/[[:punct:]]//isg;
    if ($seen{lc($_)}) {    
        print OUTFILE $_;
    }
}
close OUTFILE;
```